# Can we do representation theory for algebras with >2 operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, universal-algebra

Suppose I define an algebra with 3 or more operations, perhaps using universal algebra.  Would it be meaningful to talk about the representation theory of this algebra?

In particular, I am interested in **relation algebras**, these have 3 or more binary operations and at least 2 unary operations (negation and complement) obeying rather complicated distributive laws.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example with $3$ operations. We are studying [post-Lie algebras](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_51_postlie_2.pdf), which have three operations on a given vector space, namely two Lie brackets $[x,y]$ and $\{x,y\}$ and another bilinear product $x\cdot y$. All three operations are interwined in a certain way. They arise, among other things, in simply transitive actions of a Lie group $G$ on another Lie group $N$ by affine transformations.
One may associate to it Post-Lie algebra modules.

Comment: In such a case, how does matrix multiplication relate to the 3 products?

Comment: There is a generalization of bimodules to $n$-ary modules, see [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/n-ary-li.pdf). Furthermore, there is a generalization of modules for algebras with $2$ binary operations (e.g. Poisson algebras), see [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927870008827025).